# Async method runs fine, but does not change anything

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8.1

I want to read a XML file from the Web with following method.

```
 public static async void Load_WinPhone(string URL)
    {

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var httpResponseMessage = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(URL));

        if (httpResponseMessage.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var xmlStream = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

            XDocument Xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlStream);

            var query = from data in Xdoc.Descendants("article")
                          select new MyClass
                          {
                              Title = data.Element("title").Value                              
                          }


            foreach (MyClass x in query)
            {
                AnotherClass.List.Add(x);
            }
    }
```

This Works, but after the method finished the AnotherClass.List is still empty. 
I think it is because of the async, I tried this in the console without the async and it worked fine.
But now i want to to this on a Windows Phone 8.1 and the list stays empty.

Can someone explain me why or even have a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's how `await` works - from the point of view of the caller, it's basically the same thing as a `return`. So when you call this method, it most likely returns on the first `await` - long before `AnotherClass.List` is modified.

The main problem you have is that your method is `async void` - you're throwing away all the information about the method's execution. Instead, you want to return `Task` - this allows you to `await` the method or bind a continuation to it.

Whenever you break the `await` chain, you also break the synchronicity of the code. Most of the time (especially in UI), you want to `await` all the way to the top - usually, the only thing that's `async void` is the event handlers, and even  then it's only because event handlers *must* return `void`.

Overall, multi-threading and asynchronous code is a rather big topic - http://www.albahari.com/threading/ is a great start on understanding most of the fundamentals, as well as ways to handle it well in C#.